# go autocomplete not working in Atom Editor

Tags: go, atom-editor

I am trying to enable autocompletion for standard libraries of Go, in the Atom editor. I installed gocode, but got this notification:

[image]

When searching for "autocomplete-go" in the "Install Packages" pane, the search results dont include a "autocomplete-go". I looked into the Github repo for it (https://github.com/joefitzgerald/autocomplete-go). Of the "required" packages, "autocomplete" package is deprecated, and "go-config" also doesnt match a result in "Install Packages" search. 
I have updated the packages for Go, but that didn't help:

[image]

I am unable to see autocompletes for any standard libraries, like fmt.

My environment setup for Go in Atom is:

```
$ go version
go version go1.10.2 windows/amd64

$ go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\emuanir\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\emuanir\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\emuanir\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build841907702=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin which you have installed "https://github.com/joefitzgerald/autocomplete-go" uses "gocode" in the background to perform the auto completes. So you should have a "gocode" process running on your machine. Can you check it?

You can run `ps -aef | grep [g]ocode` from you command line. If there's no such process, you can start it by running `gocode` from your command line.

If you don't have the "gocode" installed or you cannot find the `gocode` command. Run `go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode` to install it. This will create the "gocode" binary in your `$GOPATH/bin`. So make sure `$GOPATH/bin` in added to your `$PATH`.

Comment: Hello, I have a Windows workstation. Task Manager shows that "gocode" process is running indeed, and I checked %PATH% env variable does have $GOPATH/bin in it. The thing is: its not whether the package works or not. The problem is rather that it doesnt even show up when I search for it in "Install Packages".